# Sort the Dataframe groups while retaining original rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is the original dataframe:

```
Name Version Cost
A    0.0.3   1.7
C    0.0.2   2.5
A    0.0.1   1.0
C    0.0.1   2.4
B    0.0.2   3.7
B    0.0.1   3.5
A    0.0.2   1.4
C    0.0.3   2.6
B    0.0.3   3.8
```

After grouping and sorting within groups using the following code:

```
df = df.sort_values(['Name', 'Version'], ascending=[True, False])
df = df.groupby(['Name'], sort=False)
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(['Cost'], ascending=False))
```

Now I have this dataframe where the Cost is sorted within group and groups ordered alphabetically.

```
     Name Version Cost
Name
A    A    0.0.3   1.7
     A    0.0.2   1.4
     A    0.0.1   1.0
B    B    0.0.3   3.8
     B    0.0.2   3.7
     B    0.0.1   3.5
C    C    0.0.3   2.6
     C    0.0.2   2.5
     C    0.0.1   2.4
```

Question is, now I would like to sort the groups by **total cost** of each group so the expected the result looks like this:

```
Name Version Cost
B    0.0.3   3.8
B    0.0.2   3.7
B    0.0.1   3.5
C    0.0.3   2.6
C    0.0.2   2.5
C    0.0.1   2.4
A    0.0.3   1.7
A    0.0.2   1.4
A    0.0.1   1.0
```

How can I achieve it with without losing the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.assign(groupsum=df.groupby(level=0)['Cost'].transform('sum'))\
  .sort_values(['groupsum', 'Version'], ascending=False)
```

Output:

```
       Name Version  Cost  groupsum
Name                               
B    8    B   0.0.3   3.8      11.0
     4    B   0.0.2   3.7      11.0
     5    B   0.0.1   3.5      11.0
C    7    C   0.0.3   2.6       7.5
     1    C   0.0.2   2.5       7.5
     3    C   0.0.1   2.4       7.5
A    0    A   0.0.3   1.7       4.1
     6    A   0.0.2   1.4       4.1
     2    A   0.0.1   1.0       4.1
```

And, you can add `reset_index(drop=True)` at the end:

```
  Name Version  Cost  groupsum
0    B   0.0.3   3.8      11.0
1    B   0.0.2   3.7      11.0
2    B   0.0.1   3.5      11.0
3    C   0.0.3   2.6       7.5
4    C   0.0.2   2.5       7.5
5    C   0.0.1   2.4       7.5
6    A   0.0.3   1.7       4.1
7    A   0.0.2   1.4       4.1
8    A   0.0.1   1.0       4.1
```

Or, using your "original" dataframe above:

```
df.assign(groupsum=df.groupby('Name')['Cost'].transform('sum'))\
  .sort_values(['groupsum', 'Version'], ascending=[False,False])
```

Output:

```
  Name Version  Cost  groupsum
8    B   0.0.3   3.8      11.0
4    B   0.0.2   3.7      11.0
5    B   0.0.1   3.5      11.0
7    C   0.0.3   2.6       7.5
1    C   0.0.2   2.5       7.5
3    C   0.0.1   2.4       7.5
0    A   0.0.3   1.7       4.1
6    A   0.0.2   1.4       4.1
2    A   0.0.1   1.0       4.1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this actually works! But one thing I noticed is that although it was sable to sort the groups using `groupsum`, the order for `Cost` was somehow messed up. I was able to fix it by changing `['groupsum', 'Version']` to `['groupsum', 'Cost']`

Comment: @RonZhang You're welcome.  Happy coding!  Be safe, stay healthy.

Answer (score 1):

You can create temporary column and sort by it. Then drop that column:

```py
df["tmp"] = df.groupby("Name")["Cost"].transform("sum")
df = df.sort_values(by="tmp", ascending=False).drop("tmp", 1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Name Version  Cost
3    B   0.0.3   3.8
4    B   0.0.2   3.7
5    B   0.0.1   3.5
6    C   0.0.3   2.6
7    C   0.0.2   2.5
8    C   0.0.1   2.4
0    A   0.0.3   1.7
1    A   0.0.2   1.4
2    A   0.0.1   1.0
```

---

`df` used:

```py
Name Version Cost
A    0.0.3   1.7
A    0.0.2   1.4
A    0.0.1   1.0
B    0.0.3   3.8
B    0.0.2   3.7
B    0.0.1   3.5
C    0.0.3   2.6
C    0.0.2   2.5
C    0.0.1   2.4
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, somehow I'm getting this error when creating the temp column: `'Name' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous.`

Answer (score 1):

Starting from your original dataframe, you can generate a helper column of group sums with `transform` and sort according to that and also `Version` column both in descending order:

```
group_sums = df.groupby("Name").Cost.transform("sum")
out = (df.assign(sorter=group_sums)
         .sort_values(["sorter", "Version"], ascending=False, ignore_index=True)
         .drop(columns="sorter"))
```

where we drop the helper column `sorter` after sorting,

to get

```
>>> out

  Name Version  Cost
0    B   0.0.3   3.8
1    B   0.0.2   3.7
2    B   0.0.1   3.5
3    C   0.0.3   2.6
4    C   0.0.2   2.5
5    C   0.0.1   2.4
6    A   0.0.3   1.7
7    A   0.0.2   1.4
8    A   0.0.1   1.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, similar issue to @andrejkesely 's answer. I'm getting this error when calling the groupby function: `'Name' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous.`

Comment: I see, your index name is also `"Name"` i guess. You can do `df = df.rename_axis(index=None)` before these operations to clear its name and after these you can rename with `df = df.rename_axis(index="Name")` if you wish. This'll resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: Seems like rename_axis function needs a list-like object: 
`TypeError: Must pass list-like as 'names'`

Comment: @RonZhang It seems your original dataframe has a MultiIndex; you indeed need to put a list-like then. You can first save the names as `idx_names = df.index.names` and then `df = df.rename_axis(index=None)` and the operations in one of the answers here. Lastly restoring as `df = df.rename_axis(index=idx_names)` should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `key` argument in `sort_values` to achieve the same result as the other answers:

```
print (df.sort_values("Cost", ascending=False,
                      key=lambda _: df.groupby("Name")["Cost"].transform("sum")))

  Name Version  Cost
3    B   0.0.3   3.8
4    B   0.0.2   3.7
5    B   0.0.1   3.5
6    C   0.0.3   2.6
7    C   0.0.2   2.5
8    C   0.0.1   2.4
0    A   0.0.3   1.7
1    A   0.0.2   1.4
2    A   0.0.1   1.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, similar issue to @andrejkesely 's answer. I'm getting this error when calling the groupby function: `'Name' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous.`